# Десериализация в автомаппере

Tags: c#, automapper

Есть код:

```
        CreateMap<Mnemoelement, MnemoelementDTO>()
            .ForMember(nameof(MnemoelementDTO.Settings), opt => opt.MapFrom(me => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<__type__>(me.Settings)));
```

__type__ - варьируется в зависсимости от свойства `me.Type` (`string`)

Например если `me.Type == "LINE"`, то десериаллизоваться должно в тип `LineSettings`,
если `me.Type == "CIRCLE"`, то десериаллизоваться должно в тип `CircleSettings`.

Если во внутрь `MapFrom` как-то вставить `switch`, то это поможет, только вот как?

Как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Маппер существует для маппинга A на Б. Зачем в нем делать какую то сериализацию? Если вам надо десериализовать что то куда то, делайте это отдельно от маппинга.

Comment: @tym32167 вы правильно сказали...он нужен чтобы мапить...а что если у меня в `entity` моделе `json`, а в `DTO` я хочу запихнуть нормальынй класс для работы с этим `json'ом`? Но проблема даже не в этом, а в том, что когда я десереализую, то у меня может быть один из нескольких классов (а какой именно я могу узнать по одному из его свойству) И получается так, что мне нужно подставить \__type__. Но как это сделать я не знаю

Comment: То есть вам надо: 1) Шаг первый - десериализовать ваши классы по вашей логике, какая бы эта логика не была 2) Шаг дваю Собрать эти десериализованные классы вместе (в коллекцию или как поля другого класса) 3) Шаг три - имея на руках уже нужные десериализованные классы, делать свои маппинги. Тестировать каждый шаг отдельно. Маппинг не должен зависетть от сспособа, как вы извлекли класс из БД

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы при мапинге выполнять какую-то кастомную логику, можно реализовать свой `ResolverMember` например так:

```
    public class ResolverMnemoelement : IValueResolver<Mnemoelement, MnemoelementDTO, ISettings>
    {

        ISettings IValueResolver<Mnemoelement, MnemoelementDTO, ISettings>.Resolve(Mnemoelement source, MnemoelementDTO destination, ISettings destMember, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            ISettings result = null;
            switch (source.Type)
            {
                case "LINE":
                    {
                        result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LineSettings>(source.Settings);
                        break;
                    }
                case "CIRCLE":
                    {
                        result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CircleSettings>(source.Settings);
                        break;
                    }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

И потом так использовать:

```
      CreateMap<Mnemoelement, MnemoelementDTO>()
            .ForMember(meDTO => meDTO.LinkType, opt => opt.MapFrom(me => Enum.Parse(typeof(EMnemoelementLinkType), me.LinkType)))
            .ForMember(meDTO => meDTO.Type, opt => opt.MapFrom(me => Enum.Parse(typeof(EMnemoelementType), me.Type)))
            .ForMember(meDTO => meDTO.Settings, opt => opt.MapFrom(new ResolverMnemoelement()));
```

Это позволит смапить модели:

```
/// <summary>
/// Элемент на мнемосхеме
/// </summary>
[Table(name: "mnemoelements", Schema = "public")]
public class Mnemoelement : IEntitySingleId<int>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Идентификатор
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Тип ссылки
    /// MNEMO | GROUP
    /// </summary>
    [Column("link_type")]
    [MaxLength(15)]
    [Required]
    public string LinkType { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Идентификатор для LinkType
    /// </summary>
    [Column("identifier")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Тип элемента
    /// "LINE" | "CIRCLE" | "ICON" | "TEXT" | "LINK"
    /// </summary>
    [Column("type")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Настройки для конкретного элемента
    /// </summary>
    [Column("settings")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string Settings { get; set; }
}
```

И

```
public class MnemoelementDTO
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Идентификатор
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Iдентифікатор", ShortName = "#")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Тип ссылки
    /// MNEMO | GROUP
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Тип посилання")]
    public EMnemoelementLinkType LinkType { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Идентификатор для LinkType
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Iдентифікатор")]
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Тип элемента
    /// "LINE" | "CIRCLE" | "ICON" | "TEXT" | "LINK"
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Тип елементу")]
    public EMnemoelementType Type { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Настройки для конкретного элемента
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Налаштування")]
    public ISettings Settings { get; set; }
}
```

При этом в модели `ISettings` может быть любая из доступных моделей настроек

```
public interface ISettings
{

}

public class LineSettings : ISettings
{
    public Tuple<Point, Point> Position { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; } = "#ffffff";
    public double Size { get; set; } = 2.0;

    public class Point
    {
        double X { get; set; }
        double Y { get; set; }
        public Point(int x, int y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }
    }
}

public class CircleSettings : ISettings
{
    public Point Position { get; set; }
    public double Radius { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; } = "#ffffff";
    public double BorderSize { get; set; } = 1.0;
    public string BorderColor{ get; set; } = "#ffffff";
    public double Size { get; set; } = 2.0;

    public class Point
    {
        double X { get; set; }
        double Y { get; set; }
        public Point(int x, int y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }
    }
}
```

p.s. Решение было найдено в [документации автомапера](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html)